# ios, webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch recognition on scrolling list is broken

Tags: ios, css, webkit, scroll

as discussed [here in the apple forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/885616#885616) when using `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on a list, the touch recognition becomes broken.

1. initiate a scroll
2. touch a list element while the list is still scrolling

The element being touched is not the only actually hit but the one touched in Step 1 to initiate the scrolling. I tried to replicate the native scrolling using iScroll but failed. The scrolling was very slow und quite unusable. Is there any way for a work around despite waiting for the list to stop? :( Thx in advance

*edit*

Workaround for now:

check for scrolling via:

```
$('.myList').on('touchmove', function(event {
  App.set('scroll', true);
});
```

reject the first touch after a scroll:

```
click : function(event) {

  if (App.get('scroll')) {
    App.set('scroll', false);
    return false;
  } else {
    this.performClick();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now all ios users have to touch twice... Is there a way to catch the coordinates of the first touch and simulate a second touch at the same coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your description is that you're having a jagged scroll effect. I think you might have hover events taking focus instead of touch and scroll events.

If you have :hover set for the list item (Or any of its parent or child elements), it will interfere with your touch. The touch device will first simulate the hover effect, and then your click/scroll event. This leads to a jagged scroll. Clear all :hover states and check again if you get the same problem.

I had written a detailed article and presentation about responsive design. You can find it [here](http://www.slideshare.net/gkrocks/responsive-web-design3atipsandtricks-2). Please check sections 8,9 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply wrapping list in extra div with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` helped to overcome the issue.